# How to use the project path in other method?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to get the project path and then use it, to find a file.
The problem is that it not returned in the correct format.
For example this is the response:

```
X:\Project_11_01_2021\test
```

and to use it I need it to be

```
X:\\Project_11_01_2021\\test
```

I use it in selenium to select the path to upload a file

```
.sendKeys(
               path);
```

Is their a way to get the value and use it in other function?

```
String path2 = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

I used it in windows computer

Comment: "and to use it I need it to be [...]" where are you going to use it that it needs escaped backslashes?

Comment: I want to create a method that will return the path of a file that I want to upload, and it will be generic windows or mac. so I need the path of the project and than I will add the file name

Answer (score 0):

So if your problem is just, that the path is formatted wrong that is no problem. You just use [pythons string replace function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm) and do something like this:

```
path.replace("\", "\\")
```

and you should be ready to go. If not, I don't really understand your problem...